# What is Java equivalent for .net EnvelopedCms

Tags: java, oracle, oracle11g, encryption-asymmetric

I need to rewrite the .net function below to java **without using BouncyCastle**. Because it has to be run as java stored procedure at oracle 11g database (it has java 1.5). JARs loaded into database are unpacked and that's why variant with BouncyCastle fails: JCE cannot authenticate the provider BC.

Or if someone know how to load the jar (understand the whole jar) into oracle database jvm. loadjava extracts classes that's why it can't work with BC.

```
protected byte[] Encrypt(ref byte[] content, ref X509Certificate2[]     recipients)
{
  ContentInfo ci = new ContentInfo(content);
  EnvelopedCms cms = new EnvelopedCms(ci);
  CmsRecipientCollection rcps = new CmsRecipientCollection();
  foreach (var recipient in recipients)
  {
    rcps.Add(new CmsRecipient(recipient));
  }
  cms.Encrypt(rcps);
  return cms.Encode();
}
```

Comment: Is there any solution with bouncyCastle?